# How do You Print PHP Object to Separate HTML Page

Tags: php, html, mysql

so I have:

```
$url = unserialize(base64_decode($info['story_frame']));

print $url->html;
```

On my php page but want to be able to format the printed code and chose where in the html it goes. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can also require the above page in the other html page.. anyways for even requesting the POST object, u have to anyways convert it to a php page. So now u have two ways of achieving it..

- One requesting the POST object.

i.e

first phppage

```
      <?php
      $url = unserialize(base64_decode($info['story_frame']));
      ?>

      <form action="urhtmlpage.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $url ?>">
      </form>
```

destination php page

```
      <?php echo $_POST['url'] ?>
```

- Requiring the other page in your new page.
  first phppage

  ```
     <?php  
     $url = unserialize(base64_decode($info['story_frame']));
     ?>
  ```

destination php page

```
      <?php
      require("yourphppage.php");
      echo $url; 
      ?>
```

But for both ways convert your HTML page into PHP page

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make that other html page a php page and then request post.

[Post to another page within a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1217824/773263)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you put this code in a page called "print.php".

On the code which you would want to put the output on, try the following:

```
<div class="formatMe">
    <?php include 'print.php'; ?>
</div>
```

You will be able to move the div around as you please, and the content will move with it.