# Send email when submit button is pressed

Tags: forms, email

I have a really simple form that allows a user to input an email address here:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.mydomain.com/page2/">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This works correctly and it takes the visitor to www.mydomain.com/page2 when the submit button is clicked.

I am trying to get it to email me this input email address also when the submit button is clicked.  I understand how to email using PHP but can the action have two urls?

Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Just send email while rendering `/page2/`. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `/page2/` access the email in the global variable `$_POST['email']`.  And then you can send it to yourself with PHP [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  Example:

```
mail('myemail@domain.com', 'Someone submitted my form', 'Their email was: ' . $_POST['email']);
```

If you are stuck somewhere else, let me know and I can update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once a form is submitted, you are no longer on that page. You've navigated away.

The other way you can do this is submit the first action via AJAX, then submit the form naturally to the second destination. I would suggest using jQuery to make your AJAX calls since most of the AJAX code is already there for you to use.

Another option is to have page2 be a php script, and have it perform the two actions once it receives the form data. See: [Post to another page within a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217824/post-to-another-page-within-a-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how to email using PHP

Then I would recommend writing some PHP code that sends the email to you.

> but can the action have two urls?

No.  A web browser can't make two requests at the same time.  Which response would take precedence?

Nor does it need to.  Now, you have a target already:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/page2/
```

Don't you control that page?  That would be the page on which you'd put your PHP code for sending an email.  If you *don't* control that page, then you would want an intermediary page.  Something like:

```
sendmailandredirect.php
```

(Named solely to illustrate intent, you can call it what you like.)  What this page would do is send the email, then issue a redirect to your final target.  Something like:

```
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/page2/');
```

In effect, there would be "two urls" but they're invoked in serial instead of in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the code seperate and the action url as /page2/ you could fire off an ajax request on submit to your sendmail handler.