# Send/Post Form Data to Url with PHP

Tags: php, forms, api, post

I have a form that submits via POST and I capture the variables once the form is submitted.

How can I concatenate the form data and then POST it to the url then re-direct to the thank you page?

This is not the exact code, I just can't find any normal answers, and I'm sure there is more than one way to do this. Just trying to figure out the simplest way possible.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$url = 'https://api.this.com/foo/bar?token=IHAVETOKEN&foo=$Var1&bar=$var2'

post_request_to($url);

header("Location: thankyou.php");
}
```

EDIT:

HERE IS THE ACTUAL ANSWER/WORKING CODE:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $firstName = $_GET['firstname'];
  $lastName = $_GET['lastname'];
  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $password = $_GET['password'];
  $phone = $_GET['phone'];
}

  $data = array(
        'token' => 'sadfhjka;sdfhj;asdfjh;hadfshj',
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'phone' => $phone

    );


  $postvars = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.com/foo/bar?');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

  curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: you realize you have a parse error for what you posted. Plus, variables won't parse in single quotes.

Comment: it's not the exact code. I can't find just a general way to do this.

Comment: Plus, variables are case-sensitive. Your code failed on quite a few levels.

Comment: if you're not going to post the exact code, then I won't be of any more help.

Comment: no problem Fred

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] then edit your question.

Comment: look into cURL.

Comment: This is a wee-bit too broad. Why not turn your psuedo-code into real code and if it doesn't work or something maybe come back. I think the SO community is being way to generous here, this really is kind of a broad question for so many answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

> (PHP 5, PHP 7) http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string

Example:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

---

The rest depends on your flow logic. To post to another script:

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217824/post-to-another-page-within-a-php-script):

> Possibly the easiest way to make PHP perform a POST request is to use
> [cURL](https://curl.se/), either as an [extension](https://www.php.net/curl) or simply shelling out to another
> process. Here's a post sample:

```
// where are we posting to?
$url = 'http://example.com/script.php';

    // what post fields?
    $fields = array(
       'field1' => $field1,
       'field2' => $field2,
    );
    
    // build the urlencoded data
    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);
    
    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    
    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch)
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Matthew bet you are. You need to glue them together to work within your code. The examples in my answer should give you a good headstart. If you face an issue, just shoot me a comment and I will try to help. If my answer is actually what you are looking for, marking it as **the answer** to your question will be the next thing to do.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gave me exactly what I needed to get where I needed to go.

Answer (score 0):

to concatenate url and do post method with `file_get_contents`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
  $var2 = $_POST['var2'];

  $url = 'https://api.this.com/foo/bar?token=IHAVETOKEN&foo='.$Var1.
  '&bar='.$var2;


  $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
  );

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  header("Location: thankyou.php");
}
```

you can also using `curl`