# CodeIgniter 4 view

Tags: codeigniter, view

Any one can tell me how to view a PHP page in a new tab from CodeIgniter 4 controller. I tried this code:

```
return view('/pdfrepo/resume-page-pdf',$data, array('target' => '_blank'));
```

the page is viewed with no error at all, but on the same tab!.

Answer (score 1):

rendering a view is not the same as clicking on a link:

**rendering a view:**
if you look at the docs [Global Functions and Constants - view](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#view) you'll see that third "options" parameter you are using is meant for a completely different concept as you try to apply it to, like the styling of an  `<a href>`, which in your example doesn't even exist (yet):

> $options (array) – An array of options that will be passed to the
> rendering class.
> Currently, these options are available for use within the $options array: `saveData`, `cache`, `debug`

**clicking a link:**
check the documentation [URL Helper - anchor](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?#anchor) where you would use the attributes parameter to add something like: `['target' => 'blank']` to achieve a link which opens a new tab

> P.S.
> [`_blank`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target):
> usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new
> window instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What about passing the $data variable?

Comment: you could use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339078/2275490 or [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't open a new tab and display the data. PHP is a [Server Side Language](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/server-side-client-side-programming/). for this, you have to use a [Client Side Language](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/server-side-client-side-programming/) such as JavaScript.

**In your main view**

```
<a href="<?= base_url('controller/route') ?>" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

[`target="_blank"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) which performs the miracle that loads the page in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you dear for your responses. The ['target'='_blank'] performs the miracle as you said but I need also to pass multi-dimension array, i.e. $data variable.

Comment: @Abdulla congrats to your Codeigniter Gold Badge, 3rd user ever to reach that badge! well done...